# Is there an easier way of creating a one center column design than this?

Tags: html, css

Just wondering if there would be an easier way of creating a one center column design than this [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/vbqsL0pL/1/)

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.centerCol {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(0,0,0,.44);
    padding: 15px;
    width: 65%;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="centerCol">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Center Column Test</h1>
        <hr>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Vivamus luctus suscipit lectus, non elementum lorem viverra eu.
        Aliquam suscipit iaculis orci eget accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
        Donec ornare ullamcorper enim, laoreet dignissim neque ullamcorper suscipit. 
        Mauris ut enim a tortor suscipit tincidunt ac ut ex. 
        Nullam quis ex in tellus sodales consectetur sit amet volutpat arcu. 
        Praesent porta quam eget tortor eleifend, a sodales ex imperdiet. Duis at tristique erat, eget sodales dui. 
        Cras turpis purus, pellentesque eu tellus sit amet, iaculis hendrerit massa. 
        Pellentesque consectetur odio elementum metus pulvinar, a sollicitudin magna facilisis.
        </p>
</div>
```

I feel like it's already quite simple enough as it is but I thought I'd ask

Comment: Might wanna ask this at Code Review

Comment: Easier? Nah, that looks fine. But you don't need `height: auto; float: none;` and your margin lines can be combined to `margin: 60px auto 20px;`

Comment: Alright I thought I needed height: auto; for it to scale when I added extra text.

Comment: I echo the comments left by @MichaelCoker. Collapse the `margin` styles into a single shorthand property. Also, when you have a hex color consisting of six identical characters (_e.g._, `#AAAAAA`), you can write the equivalent with its own "shorthand" of sorts: `#AAA`.

Comment: @Alberie a div's height is `auto` by default, so it's just redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, I'm still learnin'